# Mac terminal: command not found?

Tags: terminal

I'm working on a React app and I went into the terminal to install a package. Suddenly out of nowhere my terminal isn't working and when I type a command in the terminal I get: "npm: command not found".

Can anyone help?

I'm running High Sierra Beta

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. It may be more suitable for another site such as [apple.se] or [su] instead. The [help] has more information regarding what is appropriate to ask here. Good luck.

Comment: `npm` comes along with Node.js, the error message suggests that Node.js was not installed or there was an issue with the installation.

Comment: Thanks, yes npm and node was not installed correctly :/